# Programmatically add an element to modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010, modal-dialog

I'm trying to add a div element programmatically to a modal-dialog in SP2010.

**Here's what I've already tried**:

This function to fire from the Master Page:

```
        function addDialogBanner(){
            var dbody = $(".ms-dialog").find("div[id$='MSO_ContentDiv']");

            var diaBanner = document.createElement('div');
            diaBanner.id = 'diaBanner';

            $(dbody).prependChild(diaBanner);

            $("#diaBanner").text("WOW. SUCH BANNER.");
        }
```

Which is supposed to piggy-back off of this (which is added to the onload function array, also on the Master Page):

```
        function addNewItemFix() {
            $(".ms-addnew").each(function () {
                if ($(this).is("a")) {
                    var gReference = $(this).attr("href");
                    var options = {
                        title: "New Item",
                        url: gReference
                    };

                    $(this).attr("onclick", "javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({title: 'New Item',url:'" + gReference + "', dialogReturnValueCallback:RefreshOnDialogClose}); addDialogBanner(); return false;");
                }
            });

        }
```

I've added that method in because custom functionality didn't open up modal dialogs for new items. The issue I'm running into is that it seems that my script is executing before the modal dialog even finishes loading, so none of my jQuery selectors don't even exist yet. I want to stay away from `setTimeout` because load times aren't always consistent. As well, I have hundreds of sites and thousands of libraries that make an individual fix impossible.

Is the entire way I'm going about this wrong? Or am I missing some kind of key information to get this working?

EDIT 2/14/14:

I've found out using a separate method to call the `SP.UI.ModalDialog...` won't actually call the dialog. It will pull up the dialog, then redirect to the aspx page. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery when function in your code. [jQuery When](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

EDIT - Try this:

```
$(this).attr("onclick", "javascript:$.when(SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({title: 'New Item',url:'" +     gReference + "', dialogReturnValueCallback:RefreshOnDialogClose})).then(function() {
   addDialogBanner();
   return false;
});");
```

However, play around with the jQuery when function if this doesn't work.

Comment: For whatever reason, this opens up a second modal dialog ontop of the Add New Item form. And when you close it, it'll do a postback and get rid of the original form.

Comment: I changed the code to apply the code to the onclick of $(this) attribute like you had it.

Comment: It still seems like it is trying to execute instead of waiting for the event to fire. I'm getting the error `Object doesn't support property or method 'showModalDialog'` while debugging.

Comment: It might help to actually read what you edited. I made your changes and now it bypasses the modal dialog altogether. It'll load up, and it seems to redirect straight to the aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the script on the form in SharePoint designer by editing the form itself. 
Lists and Libraries -> Select List -> New Form Button

insert:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //your scripts
 });
```

inside script tags anywhere on the form.

Comment: I have hundreds of site and thousands of lists to edit simultaneously, and expansion of that is indefinite. Inserting that on every list would be impossible without an army of copy pasters. Sorry, I should have said that.